# type casting in mysql

Tags: mysql, casting

i have passportno(varchar) in database.
 i am entering values like this 001,002,003. and  i want to display like sorting order.

now i wrote query like this `"select * from passport_registration where status=1 ORDER BY passportno"`  then displaying output like this......`077,088,099,100,1000,1001,1009,101,1010`
i want to diplay sort order. how to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ORDER BY CAST(passportno AS UNSIGNED)